# Transformation of a quadratic term into a multiplicative term

Tags: quadratic-forms

Can we always transform any quadratic term into a "linear term $\times$ linear term + linear term" form? I mean transforming something like $a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2+a_3x_1x_2+a_4$ to  $(b_1x_1+c_1)(b_2x_2+c_2)+d_1x_1+d_2x_2+d_3$.

Comment: Yes. You can do that

Comment: Using the second term as is will not  result the squares for $x_1 and x_2$.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I should have included both variables in both multiplicated linear terms.